# Как зафиксировать команду в консоли MySQL?

Tags: mysql, консоль

Вошёл в консоль mysql под пользователем. Команда:

```
-> mysqldump -u myuser -p mydbname > newdbname.sql
```

После ввода enter с новой строчки появляется стрелка продолжения ввода команды т.е. -> если поставить точку с запятой в конце команды, т.е. newdbname.sql; то появляется ошибка синтаксиса

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: вам не нужно входить в консоль mysql, эта команда выполняется в той же оболочке, что и просто `mysql`.

Comment: Не понял вас. Я захожу по SSH через putty потом из обычной консоли ввожу mysql -u myuser -p и попадаю в консоль mysql и уже там ввожу команду так?

Comment: Дело в том, что mysqldump не предназначена для mysql-консоли, это утилита, такая же, как mysql

Comment: @RoboNoob `mysql -u -p` вводить не надо, доходите до этого этапа и сразу `mysqldump`